# Does NSURLConnection choose its delegate automatically?

Tags: objective-c

Does NSURLConnection automatically send messages to the class that initialized it or how does it work because I did not reference it in my header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to specify the delegate, as in this example from the [URL Loading System Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

```
// Create the request.
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest 
                        requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]
                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                    timeoutInterval:60.0];
// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                                 initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

(note the `delegate:self` part).

Comment: One caveat: NSURLConnection retains its delegate. This caused me some fairly major headaches in the past...

Comment: Thanks I will make a note of this!